# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for localhost

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, httpclient, webclient

I have strange issue where I am able to successful connect to my remote server using WebClient or HttpClient. But the same code doesn't work when I try to connect to localhost and I get SSL/TLS channel can not be created. When I run localhost without SSL, I can connect to localhost.

i.e.

(a) **http** works with my server running remotely and also localhost
(b) **https** works with my server running remotely and NOT with localhost

the parameters I used are :

```
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 0;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
          (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
          {
              return true;
          };
```

Comment: What's the error? Is it because localhost is using a self signed cert?

Comment: Error is :

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

I do not know reason for the error...I assumed ii is because of self signed cert. But then I think by ServerCertificateValidationCallback  will fix the issue.

Any idea how to fix self signed cert issue? or the error could be because of some other reason

Comment: TLS 1.0 is obsolete so remove SecurityProtocolType.Tls.  What type of machine are you using for the server?  What version of Net is server running?  Either the operating system on server is old or the version of Net on Server is old.